# codeigniter+HMVC cross module call controller->method

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am pulling all my hair off... Have been searching every thread, would appreciate if someone can point me to a working example.

Accroding to the doc: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc
I can call another module->controller using

```
modules::run('module/controller/method', $params);
modules::load('module/controller/method', $params);
or
$this->load->module('module/controller');
$this->controller->method();
```

**Problem:** the "method()" is never called. only constructor of the controller is called every time.

The objective is to build self-contained MVCs as module and use by other controllers.
But no matter what I do, it only calls the constructor, method is not called.
I started using HMVC a few weeks ago, did I miss something in the doc or it is not used this way?
Here is the setup:

```
modules
  |--ztest1
  |   |--controller/c1.php
  |--ztest2
      |--controller/c2.php

class C1 extends MX_Controller {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
  function index () {
    Modules::run('ztest2/c2/testc2/');
    //Modules::load('ztest2/c2/testc2/');
    //$this->load->module('ztest2/c2/testc2/');
    //$this->c2->testc2();
  }
}

class C2 extends MX_Controller {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo __FILE__." // ".__CLASS__."/".__FUNCTION__.PHP_EOL;
  }
  function testc2(){
    echo __FILE__." // ".__CLASS__."/".__FUNCTION__.PHP_EOL;
  }
}

output:
/app/modules/ztest2/controllers/c2.php // C2/__construct
```

additional note: no error or warning with the script. It just quietly calls the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HMVC works well for me. I'm working on a project using this HMVC now.
Just edit `third_party/MX/Modules.php` as shown in this link below and tell me the response.

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/pull-request/5/return-error-messages-instead-of-logging/diff

Comment: Thanks for the link! I got this message: Module controller failed to run: ztest2/c2/testc2/

Comment: It's solved. I have put my finding in answer below. I accepted your answer because it helped me debug this thing. Did not know HMVC throw error to log only. thanks!

Comment: @Reed, Now i'm working on a project with this HMVC so I'm learning through this

Comment: @Reed The accepted answer should be the actual answer which solves the problem.

Answer (score 24):

Thanks for MC's tip, I finally figured out the cause.  HMVC doc indeed lacks some examples for beginner.

For anyone who may find this thread in the future, correct usage here:

```
to call module01/controller01/method00:

//method 1 CORRECT:
$ctlObj = modules::load('module01/controller01/');
$ctlObj->method00();
//or you could use chaining:
modules::load('module01/controller01/')->method00();

//method 1 WRONG:
modules::load('module01/controller01/method00');  //this will only load contructor

---
//method 2 CORRECT:
modules::run('module01/controller01/method00');   //no trailing slash!

//method 2 WRONG:
modules::run('module01/controller01/method00/');  

---
//method 3 CORRECT:
$this->load->module('module01/controller01');
$this->controller01->method00();
```

I don't understand why method 3 failed when I first try... maybe because I restarted HTTPD?

Comment: Thank you Reed. This will help beginners. UPVOTE :)

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy what is not working for you? all 3 methods?

Comment: @Reed, None of them :-(

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. Too bad I can only give one thumbs up. :)

Comment: @Reed If I use same controller name in the other module, and run that module's method in a controller that having the same name, it throws an error saying "call to undefined method".

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.  Make sure you check capitalization of your directories and and controllers.  It's not case sensitive for differing between the module and controller name.

```
//In my case the below did not work
$this->load->module('dashboard/Dashboard');
$this->Dashboard->method();


//but 
$this->load->module('dashboard');
$this->Dashboard->method();
//worked
```

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts to achieve call a controller that is not located within any module.

```
Modules::run('../Controller/method');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new at CI as well, and I thought I was having the same issue. Script seemed not to be running. (no html output).

```
//This did NOT work (did not produce output)
modules::run('module_name/method_name',$data); 

// but this DID work???  didn't know why
modules::run('module_name/method_name',$data); 
exit();

// turns out you need the echo for output
echo modules::run('templates/login_template',$data);
```

This may be obvious to many of you- but I wasted two hours searching for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

so According to the documentation they says copy the controller in default controller folder and move to modules controller.

So now how do I run the controller that has been moved to modules when I run its running from the default controller file if removed does not work so how to make it run the controller inside module as a default controller to run.

So Do I need to mention the modules name too in the route

Answer (score 0):

```
  /*echo Modules::run("controller name of a module which you want to call/and its.. function name");*/

echo Modules::run("Second/callit");
```

or

```
$this->load->module('Second');

$this->second->callit();
```

But.. the controller name shold be different .. from one module to another module..

```
                       **(parameter passing)**

        echo "<hr>";

       //echo Modules::run("controller name of a module which you want to call/and its.. function name");

         $data="peter";

      echo Modules::run("Second/callit",$data);

      echo "<hr>";

      $this->load->module('Second');

     $this->second->callit($data);

      echo "<hr>";
```