# Use controller from another controller CodeIgniter and HMVC

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I want to load a function from another controller. This is my structure:

```
- modules
--orderpages
---controllers
----WebshopCore.php
----WebshopController.php
```

My function insertItemInCart in WebshopController.php is called. But when i want to execute a function from another controller it crashes.

```
class WebshopController extends MX_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('orderPages/WebshopCore');
    }

    function insertItemInCart(){
        $partId = $this->input->post('partId');
        $quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');

        $output = $this->WebshopCore->getPickLocations($partId,$quantity);  

    }
}
```

My WebshopCore:

```
class WebshopCore extends MX_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getPickLocations($partId,$amount){
        $result = "test";

        return $result;
    }
}
```

What goes wrong? I don't get it

**The solution:**

```
$output = modules::load('orderPages/WebshopCore/')->getPickLocations($partId,$quantity);
```

Comment: imo, debugging: `var_dump($this->WebshopCore, __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately before `$output = ....`. Yopu should see the WebshopCore object.

Comment: @RyanVincent
NULL string(107) "/Applications/AMPPS/www/cart.local/application/modules/orderPages/controllers/WebshopController.php19" This is what i get back

Comment: @RyanVincent I did that already

Comment: You checked that `$this->load->module('orderPages/WebshopCore');` returns what you expect? It obviously doesn't as the call to the loaded module 'WebshopCore' fails?

Comment: @RyanVincent How can i check what it returns? But I get no errors on that line

Comment: maybe interesting? [Use controller from another controller codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947261/codeigniterhmvc-cross-module-call-controller-method). This is the end of my knowledge of 'CI'.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for you help!! It works now, the solution is in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome - glad it is working :)

Comment: I'd suggest that you write a self-answer to your question (and even accept it after some days) and explain why it is working now, so other users may actually benefit from your question

Comment: And your controller file name and class name should be like Webshopcore.php and `class Webshopcore extends MX_Controller {}` ucfirst for all file names and classes.

Comment: It is most of the time `modules::run('module/controller/function')`

Answer (score 0):

You should write a library in that case.

In application/libraries create Cart.php (or whatever you want)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cart
{
  protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance(); 
    }

    public function getPickLocations($partId, $qty)
    {
       //Your stuff
    }

}
```

And then in your controllers :

```
 $this->load->library("cart");
 $data = $this->cart->getPickLocations($this->input->post('partId'), $this->input->post('quantity'));
```

Comment: Yes that is an option, but what i have read on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947261/codeigniterhmvc-cross-module-call-controller-method is that the hmvc model can do this on a much shorter way.