# how to run module to secondary controller codeigniter hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I have  2 controller controllers placed in my administration module which are:

- modules/administration/controllers/Administration.php
- modules/administration/controllers/Customers.php

The problem i have is when i want to display customer details in the admin view via:

```
echo modules::run('administration/customers/view_all');
```

I get nothing of course it looks as if codeigniter is looking for a (customers) method inside the administration controller. Has anyone else encountered this issue and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: How about `partial views`?

Comment: all i want is return the data to the view file which is placed in the administration views folder  so i am not entirely sure what you mean by partial view

Comment: You just want to call a method from a different controller that renders a view, right...I have the code to do that, I am going to post it as soon as I got home :)

Comment: i have 2 controllers inside my module  i want to echo modules run  a function from one of the controller to another whitin the same module for example echo modules:: run ('administration/customers/view_all_customers and displaying it in the administration view  administration being the module customers being the controller and view_all_customers being the method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter+HMVC cross module call controller->method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947261/codeigniterhmvc-cross-module-call-controller-method)